# How to use an If statement in a for loop to check if an option is selected

Tags: php, html

Hello I am currently trying to get the current week as selected but since I use a for loop I am not sure how to implement the if statement in an option.

here is my code:

```
<?php
$datum = date(W);
for ($z = 1; $z < 52; $z++)
{
    ?>
    <option value=<?php echo $z ?> <?php echo "week: ".$z ?> </option>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I was thinking about something like this:

```
<option value=<?php echo $z ?> If($z == $datum) then selected <?php echo "week: ".$z ?> </option>
```

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: echo ($z == $datum)?$z:'anything you want'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$datum = date(W);
for ($z = 1; $z < 52; $z++)
{
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $z ?>" <?php if($z == $datum) { echo "selected"; } ?> > <?php echo "week: ".$z; ?> </option>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: @user2479441.Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a dropdown option as selected by setting the property of that element as `selected`. Try with

```
<option value="<?php echo $z;?>" <?php if($z == $datum) echo "selected";?> > 
  <?php echo "week: ".$z; ?> 
 </option>
```